# What does "Closed pull requests" mean in the output of `brew search`?

Tags: macos, package, homebrew

What does "Closed pull requests" mean in the output of `brew search`?

I'm familiar with Git pull requests, and understand that developers may push updates to a project.

But why does Brew reports that two versions of `objconv` has been submitted without letting me download them?

```
nlykkei-mbp:Projects nlykkei$ brew search objconv
No formula or cask found for "objconv".
Closed pull requests:
objconv 2.24 (new formula) (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/6804)
Added objconv (https://github.com/vertis/objconv) (https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/pull/17153)
New Formula: objconv-2.12 (https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/pull/10441)
objconv 2.36 (new formula) object and executable utilities (https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/pull/33807)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is in the [commit message](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/commit/79439626b5e7564566bdf8736916342e2bb5e1a7) introducing this feature:

```
commit 79439626b5e7564566bdf8736916342e2bb5e1a7
Author: Jack Nagel <jacknagel@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Jan 11 20:49:08 2012 -0600

    search: return matches from open pull requests

    When search can't find any local results, hit the GitHub API and search
    the titles of pending pull requests. This will help people find the many
    proposed formulae and prevent them from wasting time duplicating them.
```

You can also find details in the [corresponding issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/9018):

> It would also be great if brew search optionally returned matches from outstanding pull requests so that I could save the time of recreating a formula from scratch if someone else has already done it.

Comment: Thank you. Why does my question say "Closed pull requests", while your answer says "Pending pull requests"? Are those the same thing? Also, do you know the reason that these formulae are not included into Brew,? Some of them are quite old.

Comment: The terminology has slightly changed over time but it's the same thing. The reasons why these formulas are not included into Homebrew may vary, but in the case of objconv it's because there is no versioned downloadable release. See for example https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/pull/33807

Comment: "@OrtomalaLokni" - do you know why a static download link is required? I don't see why a dynamic download link (always pointing to the latest release) will break a package? If the formula is bottled, or the source files is download from a repository, then it doesn't matter? Is it a problem, because the formula explicitly downloads objconv from the URL (http://www.agner.org/optimize/objconv.zip) and installs it?

Comment: @Shuzheng The problem is that you cannot associate a checksum with a download link and that you cannot guarantee anything on what is being downloaded.

Comment: Ahh, I see. The "version" and "checksum" specified in the formula may not match what's downloaded from the URL, since it doesn't reflect any specific version, but always yields the latest version (i.e. is "dynamic") - Thanks.